# SQL Server query for avoiding duplicate columnes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to avoide the duplicate month rows. If there is a vlaue in sum1,sum2 or sum3 this row should be selected. If thats not the case then the rows with the nulls are fine.

[image]

thx for the help.

Comment: Please dont post screen shots.  What is your table structure, what have you tried?  Why what you have tried is not working?

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, use SUM() to sum the non-null values.

Comment: What do you mean by "selected"? Do you mean "Appear in your output"? What does the query look like that produces this?

Comment: Sorry for the Screenshot. @jarlh thx your answer solved my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to delete such rows, use something like

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (year, month, ...)
WHERE COALESCE(t1.sum1, t1.sum2, t1.sum3, t1.sum4) IS NULL
  AND COALESCE(t2.sum1, t2.sum2, t2.sum3, t2.sum4) IS NOT NULL
```

or

```sql
DELETE
FROM table t1
WHERE COALESCE(t1.sum1, t1.sum2, t1.sum3, t1.sum4) IS NULL
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM table t2
               WHERE t1.year = t2.year
                 AND t1.month = t2.month
                 AND ...
                 AND COALESCE(t2.sum1, t2.sum2, t2.sum3, t2.sum4) IS NOT NULL )
```